# Apache Netbean IDE does not open after installation

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I have a netbean plateform application that does not work after java update.
We have reinstall java and now java looks fine. I have install jdk and Netbean 12.0 but still its not showing anything after installation.

AppLauncher::findUserDir()

User home: C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming

User dir: C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming/test/dev

Option found: default_options=--branding test -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Xmx6000m -J-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -J-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30

After replacement: --branding test -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Xmx6000m -J-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -J-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30

Option found: jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321\

parseArgs():

--trace

C:\Users\trace.log

parseArgs() finished

parseConfigFile(C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming/test/dev\etc\test.conf)

trace stop at above line and not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

refer to apache site
they says :

Apache NetBeans 12.0 runs on the JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 14, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans release.

so you need to use JDK listed above.